# Codename one separate class along with statemachine class

Tags: codenameone

I am working a project in gui builder..As my project is growing bigger and bigger, i find it hard to search a particular forms and methods all in a statemachine class. so i wanted to create a separate class for each form. but since the gui builder create the methods automatically in statemachine which extends statemachineBase class. how can i use separate class for separate gui forms so that they automatically create methods in the designated class. for instance when i click before show event of form named "NextPage", the gui builder automatically create beforeNextPage method in NextPage class instead of statemachine. I did the followings but lost in the process..

NextPage.class

```
public class NextPage extends StateMachine {
    private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> mData;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> moreData;

public NextPage(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
    }

@Override
    public void beforeNextPage(Form f) {
     //.........
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms generated by GUI Builder cannot be separated from StateMachineBase into different Classes.

What I do personally is create a form in GUI to get the right Look and Feel and then create a replica of that form in code, then delete the one on GUI Builder once I'm satisfied with the code version. It makes my projects well organized and easy to debug.

BeforeShow() would be handle while the form class is loading and to do anything in PostShow(), just do this:

```
    this.addShowListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            removeShowListener(this);
            //Your postShow() codes here.
            revalidate();
        }
    });
```

Forms created in code are light-weight and more customizable than GUI forms.

Comment: For completeness I'd also mention the new gui builder where forms are separate entities https://www.codenameone.com/blog/gui-builder-walkthru.html